# How to use $mysqli->result inside while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

I am processing data retrieved from a table as

```
<?php
    $result=$mysqli->query("SELECT value1, value2 FROM table1");
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $value1 =   $row['valu1'];
            $value2 =   $row['value2'];

            $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO table2 (value1) VALUES ('$value1')");
            $result2    =   $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE value1='$value1'");
            $row2       =   $result2->fetch_assoc();
            $column1_id =   $row2['id'];
            $result2->close();

            $mysqli->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO table3 (value2) VALUES ('$value2')");
            $result3    =   $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM table3 WHERE value1='$value2'");
            $row3       =   $result3->fetch_assoc();
            $column2_id =   $row3['id'];
            $result3->close();

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO table4 (value1,value2) VALUES ('$value1','$value2')");
        }
?>
```

Bu the problem is that sub-`$result` will be messed up with the parent one, and the while loop will only work in the first cycle.

Answer (score 0):

The better should be like this

```
insert ignore into table2 (value1) select value1 from table1;
insert ignore into table3 (value2) select value2 from table1;
insert ignore into table4 (value1, value2) select value1, value2 from table1
```

This is optimized, and I dun think you would need to SELECT id .. and loop
(I dun see you are make use of the result in your example)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but this is a simplified version to discuss my issue; the actual code is more complicated with lots of php processing on values come out of table1.

Comment: yes, understand that ... then you can just run whatever logic you want  to massage the data, and output it to a file, at the end of process, do a mysql import? you would need to explicitly describe your coding environment, i'm outsider have no clue what is on your mind. anyway, loop and insert one-by-one is the worse ever solution.

Comment: The case is not strange; I have a clumsy table of data, and I want to create a normalized database by hosting data in several tables. In this process, I want to take care of the text (like formatting) by PHP.